# Pass an array of objects to another function onclick

Tags: javascript

I just want to ask how to pass an array of objects to another function.
I have a function

```
 function btnB(weekly) {
    console.log(weekly);
 }

 function btnA() { 
    const array = [{ abc : 123 }, { def : 456 }]        
    div.innerHTML = `<div onclick="btnB(${array[0]});"`;
    divList.appendChild(div);        
 }

 btnA();
```

And I'm getting an error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: well your html is not valid. and we have no clue what weekly_counts[0] is. My guess is you have something in your onclick that needs quotes. Show more code since there are unknowns

Comment: Post the whole code please.

Comment: Sorry @epascarello I forgot to edit the weekly_counts

Comment: And now the issue is the fact you expect an object reference to be the object reference when you convert it to a string. You really should use document.createElement and addEventListener to avoid these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't substitute an object like that in a template literal. It converts the object to a string, which returns `[Object object]`.

Use `JSON.stringify()` to convert it to an object literal.

```
function btnA() { 
    const array = [{ abc : 123 }, { def : 456 }]        
    div.innerHTML = `<div onclick='btnB(${JSON.stringify(array[0])});'`;
    divList.appendChild(div);        
 }
```

You also should use single quotes around the `onclick` value, because JSON uses double quotes around the object keys.

Comment: Note this may be insufficient from a security perspective if `array` isn't actually static as it's in the example: Imagine `array = [{ abc: "'}]); alert(\`XSS\`); //" }]`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function btnB(weekly) {
   console.log(weekly);
}

function btnA() { 
   const array = [{ abc : 123 }, { def : 456 }];
   const div = document.createElement('div'); // delete if useless
   div.addEventListener('click', () => {
     btnB(array[0])
   });
   divList.appendChild(div);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the `[0]` is part of your attempt to solve this, but based on the question asking to pass *an array of* objects to the click handler, I'll refer to that instead.

Inline event handlers are deprecated and problematic anyway, but using them in HTML *generated by JavaScript* completes the circle in an absurd way. It would be a lot easier and more robust (and secure) to attach the click handler via JavaScript as well, as follows:

```js
const array = [{ abc: 123 }, { def: 456 }]        
div.innerHTML = '<div></div>' // Just the inner div without onclick
div.firstElementChild.addEventListener('click', () => btnB(array))
divList.appendChild(div)
```